# Ajax request with click on link which it's class value is getted by PHP doesn't get any response

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I do want to send an HTTP request using Ajax and receive the response (picture links from the database) when the User click on a link. The parameter I put on my Ajax function call is the value of the class of the clicked link which I get through a loop in PHP. I think that's a little bit confusing.. Here's my code

> The Ajax function call in : **index.php**

```
<script>
    var current = 0;
    function showPics(str) {
        if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById("displayPic").innerHTML="";
            return;
        } 

        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("displayPic").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","getpics.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

> **getpics.php**

```
<?php
    $q = $_GET["q"];

    $host = "127.0.0.1";
    $db = "pcqsp";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $req = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM screenshot WHERE id_work = :id_work');
    $req->execute(array('id_work' => $q));

    while ($data = $req->fetch())
    {
        echo "<img class='popup_pics' src='" . $data['link_screenshot'] . "' />";
    }

    $req->closeCursor();
?>
```

> The Ajax call on **index.php**

```
<?php
    // Open a database connection 
    $host = "127.0.0.1";
    $db = "pcqsp";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $req = $conn -> query('SELECT * FROM work');
    $i = 1;
    while ($data = $req -> fetch()) { ?>
        <div class="image-even">
            <img src="<?php echo $data['cover_work'] ?>" width="421" height="590" />
        </div>
        <div class="more">
            // Here's the problem
            <a class="<?php echo $i ?>-popup" href="#displayPics">More details</a>
        </div>
        <?php
        $i ++;
    } 
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $current = 0;
    $('a[class*="popup"]').click(function(){
        current = $(this).attr('class').charAt(0);
        showPics(current); //Ajax function call
    });
</script>
```

When I was not doing the loop via PHP (I was doing it statically as writing : `1-popup`, `2-popup`, etc.. Everything was working.

Please do you have a solution of this problem ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your jquery call is not built inside the `window.ready` event. try including it in the `window.ready` event by doing the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $current = 0;
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
       $('a[class*="popup"]').click(function(){
           current = $(this).attr('class').charAt(0);
           showPics(current); //Ajax function call
       });
    });
</script>
```

it's possible that your javascript is executed before the dom is ready

Comment: can you see in your browser control if the request is generating a valid response

Comment: @DevZero Thank you for your time :) It gives me `Status : 200  OK` and  `size : 222B  0B`

Comment: your browser console for example chrome has a ajax request monitor you can see if your ajax call happens and more details about it

Comment: Thank you. I don't see the response, I guess it's the one wihch it's size is : `0 B`